# Sending key events to un focused page in google chrome with extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Google chrome extension, which will have next and previous button with it't pop up when clicked. As well a web page that actually have next and previous buttons. What I am trying to do is, when user click next button of extension pop up; it will actually trigger the click on next button of original web page which is currently not focused. I guess this can be done by tabs module, but I am not able to figure out how really it can be done.

Thanks.